# How Deep Are Bender's Insides?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

Bender often pulls large objects from his torso cupboard, but how deep or how much empty space is he capable of storing? Can he bend space around the perimeters of the frame of his torso's door? If that is the case, does it also bend time? I suppose he might bend in more ways than one...

Comment: [Hammerspace](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace) -- used for comedic effect and/or deus ex machina.. Literally.

Comment: @KeithHWeston Soo....  God lives inside Bender?

Comment: @Izkata - Well.. there was at least one episode where bender WAS god, so, yeah... :)

Answer (score 3):

As KHW states, [Benders chest cavity is a classic example of Hammerspace](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace), and his insides of are variable based on the comedic needs of the show.

I can't find a screenshot, but in the Episode "Fry and the Slurm Factory", Professor Farnsworth uses an x-ray wand to look inside Bender. Here his insides are primaily cogs with a space that seems to conform to his outer dimensions.

The episode "A Bicyclops Built for Two" establishs that Bender does have a finite capacity as Bender having stolen most of the things from the Cyclops village has become bloated with loot - however given Benders propencity for theft, this could be a rather large capacity. It also establishes a fixed *height* for Benders chest cavity, as when attempting to steal a broadsword he needs to swallow this, and it still protrudes into one of his legs leaving him with a limp.

As for how deep benders cavity is, it is hard to accurately say, however Bender in a single scene has withdrawn a [goldfish bowl, a toaster, and another two goldfish bowls](http://www.futurama-madhouse.net/scripts/2acv09.shtml), while at other times he has stored Heads in his chest cavity for extended periors of time - Lucy Liu's head was in Benders chest for 10 episodes<sup>*</sup> spanning seasons 3 and 4 - from when Bender and Lucy begin their relationship in episode [I Dated a Robot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Dated_a_Robot) until his trist with the Planet Express Ship in [Love and Rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_and_Rocket) , all without impacting his ability to withdraw a piano and candleabra in [Godfellas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godfellas).

<sup>* This supposes that Bender never took her out, but they were in a relationship. Lets assume he kept her in there. He's a jerk. Also, yes [Anthology of Interest II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_of_Interest_II) counts in this list as the gang are watching the results of their what-ifs on the "What-if Machine".</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It is variable in size. It goes from being just the size you see to being the size of the universe.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever watched Doctor Who, its just like the doctors tardis, bigger on the inside. This also applies with the doctors jacket which is also bigger on the inside.